# Состояние библиотеки wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, библиотеки

Заинтересовался библиотекой `wxPython`, но слышал, что проект умер и напрягает отсутствие версии для `python3.X`.
Кто нибудь работает с библиотекой? В каком состоянии проект?

Comment: Узнал. Библиотека продолжает развиваться, проект называется wxPython Phoenix. Здесь http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/ выкладываются готовые сборки.
Новый проект поддерживает 3 ветку python.